# Committing sqlite query takes ages when another query is waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

Take the following C++ example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>

#include "sqlite/sqlite.cpp"
#include "time/time.cpp"

microtimestamp start;
microtimestamp mid;
microtimestamp end;

void t1()
{
    sqlite my_sqlite("mydb2.db");

    my_sqlite.begin();
    my_sqlite.query("delete from x").step();

    usleep(10E6);

    start = microtime();

    my_sqlite.commit();

    mid = microtime();
}

void t2()
{
    sqlite my_sqlite("mydb2.db");

    my_sqlite.query("insert into x values(5)").step();
    end = microtime();
}

int main()
{
    std :: thread th1(t1);

    usleep(1.0E5);

    std :: thread th2(t2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    std :: cout << "To commit: " << mid - start << std :: endl; 
    std :: cout << "To do the query: " << end - mid << std :: endl;
}
```

Here `sqlite` is a library that I developed just to wrap the calls to the `sqlite3` interface, but it just forwards the calls to that interface.

I have two threads. The first starts slightly before the second. It creates a connection to a database, then begins a transaction. Then it sleeps for ten seconds. In the meantime, the second thread starts, opens a connection to the same database, and tries to execute a query.

Without any additional configuration, this results in a `SQLITE_BUSY` error returned by `sqlite3_step`. I read that I can, however, set a waiting timeout with `sqlite3_busy_timeout`. I set the timeout on the second thread database to a very high value. Now, no error is return and the second thread actually waits for the first thread to release the database before writing.

However, I have a timing problem. As you can see, I am taking three microtimestamps: before starting the commit on the first thread, after completing the commit on the first thread, and after the query is completed on the second thread.

The results are as follows:

```
To commit: 746329
To do the query: 1836
```

It looks like it takes *forever* to commit the transaction when some other thread is waiting on a `SQLITE_BUSY` to get to do its own transaction. Of course, if I disable the second thread waiting to acquire the database the first thread commits in a millisecond.

I tried doing the same thing using the `sqlite3` terminal interface instead of using the first thread. My program successfully waits until the database is released, but when I first try to commit on my terminal I get a `database locked` error. If I wait a second or so, then try again to commit, the commit is successful, the database is released and the query gets immediately completed on my program that was waiting.

What is going on? How comes that it takes so long to commit a transaction when another thread is waiting to make a transaction on the db? And why does it yield a `database locked` error **on the thread that locked the database**? Maybe I am missing something...?

Comment: How was the sqlite library compiled?  It needs to be compiled for the threading mode you wish to use see: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html  The default is **serialized** you probably want **multi-thread**

Comment: I added `sqlite3_shutdown(); sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD); sqlite3_initialize();` at the begin of my main. Is that what you meant? None of these instructions yield an error, but my problem isn't solved.

Comment: By default, a transaction does not try to take a write lock until it actually needs to write to the database file. Try using [BEGIN IMMEDIATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for write transactions.